# Google Drive SDK - upload/stream videos live

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I found a lot of resources to stream videos from google drive, but didn't find it the other way, streaming from a mobile app to google-drive, so that the local storage isn't used.

Any hint's highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean uploading from mobile to google drive?

Comment: yeah..but as a incremental live stream, not as a pre-recorded file

Comment: Gdrive doesn't support the functionality yet.

Answer (score 0):

As @Omkar Nath Singh stated, this is not yet supported. You can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features) regarding this.

> If there is a feature or functionality missing that you would like to use, you can [search our Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191650%2B%20type:feature_request) to determine if others have requested it. If it has already been requested, please star the issue (click the star next to the issue number) — we prioritize bugs that receive more stars. You can also add comments to existing issues, but you should only do this if you are adding context or additional information about the problem.
>
> If the feature hasn't been requested yet, you can [file a feature request on our Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106). Please describe the specific functionality you would like to see added, as well as reasons you think it's important. If possible, include specific details about your use case and the new opportunities the feature would allow for.